# CSS position: fixed with horizontal scroll bar for overflowing content

Tags: css, overflow

I'm using CSS `position: fixed` for a `div` tag. My browser horizontal scroll bar is moving but I'm not seeing text. This is what I tried so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .test {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
     width:2500px;
}
        body {
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="test">
            test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test datatest data     test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the text in a single line with a browser horizontal scroll bar(not div scroll bar)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want overflowing text to create a scroll bar. You have to let the browser know, it shouldn't break lines.

```
.test {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[see my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/Kq563/1/). I just added a background and padding so it's better visible.

Comment: Yes, I need to display text in single line with horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @user3194721 You said something about a vertical scrollbar in your initial question, I updated my answer.

Comment: After adding your styles I'm not seeing any horizontal scrollbar :(

Comment: @user3194721 do you have a screenshot? I works for me in Firefox 30 and Chromium 34.

Comment: sorry, I'm confusing you. I'm looking for browser scroll bar,not div scroll bar

Comment: @user3194721 What do you mean by saying 'browser scroll bar'?

Comment: @user3194721 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51372/discussion-between-kelunik-and-user3194721)

Answer (score 0):

Since you set your width to be 2500px, it is not showing in your browser view.  So, I added a specified height and reduced the width to make it obvious that they are shown.  Also set both (x and y) to scroll - you can fiddle with it as you see fit according to your needs.

```
.test {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to display text in single line with horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: well, initially you mentioned 'vertical' so that changes things :)  - in that case, add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.edit` css

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to give vertical scroll with your div you need to specify `height`.

```
.test {
  position: fixed;
  width: 2500px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, sometimes you make `position: fixed;` for some `div` that have child div inside and this child div contains the content that will be scrolled. you should add `display: flex;` to the child div.

Without adding this style to this situation, it won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the follwing:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    white-space: nowrap;
     width:2500px;
}
        body {
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="test">
            <p>test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test datatest data     test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test datatest data     test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test datatest data     test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test datatest data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data  test data</p>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.test {
    position: fixed;
    width: 2500px;
    height:100%;
}
```